# date variable in R

Tags: r, date, xts

I have an xts variable `os` and another variable called `date`.

```
head(os[,1])
        ab1   ab2
2007-07-20 103.02 96.60
2007-07-20 103.00 96.25
2007-07-20 102.70 96.25
2007-07-20 102.70 96.15
2007-07-20 102.75 96.20
2007-07-20 102.50 95.80
```

and

```
head(date)
date
2007-07-20
2007-07-21
```

If I use:

```
sum(index(os)[1]==date).
```

The answer is 1, which is correct. Just comparing the first date of `os`.

If I compare the dates from the `os` like so:

```
sum(index(os)==date)
```

The answer is 0.

How is it possible?

Comment: Can you add some sample data to your question so that we can have a go at solving your problem? You can edit your question and paste in the results of `dput(head(yourdataobject))`

Comment: Hi there! Please make your post reproducible by having a look at [**How to make a great reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for us to help you. Thank you.

Comment: Any idea how to get out of this trouble

Comment: Please do what the other suggested before we can help you, you'll get a quick answer as it's easy. We need to make the answer useable for everybody that will come next, that's why we are asking

Comment: `sum(index(os)==date)` returns 3 for me.  You need to provide a reproducible example.